# Run macros assigned to many Excel sheets of a workbook with one click

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I have one workbook with 8 worksheets.
I have a macro assigned to each worksheet.
I want to run all 8 macros from one worksheet in one click(by clicking one button, to run all 8 macros).
How can this be performed?

update this is my code

```
Sub cf1()
Application.Run "v1"
Application.Run "a1"
Application.Run "t1"
Application.Run "p1"
Application.Run "k1"
Application.Run "k2"
Application.Run "k3"
Application.Run "m1"
End Sub


Sub v1()

End Sub

.
.
.

Sub m1()

End sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new Sub that runs all the macro and assign it to a `Form Control Button`. 
Something like this:

```
Sub RunAll()
    Application.Run "MacroForSheet1"
    Application.Run "MacroForSheet2"
    .
    .
    Application.Run "MacroForSheet8"
End Sub
```

The string argument is the `macro name` or `sub procedure name` of your macro.
I use `Application.Run Method` so that you can call all macro regardless where you write them.
 If you write them in `Module` you can be explicit as well like this:

```
Application.Run "Module1.MacroForSheet1"
```

If you write them in `Sheet` then you can be explicit like this:

```
Application.Run "Sheet1.MacroForSheet1"
```

where `Sheet1` is the object codename seen in the properties window.
If this doesn't work for you, clarify and add context to your question.

**Edit1:** If you write it in `Thisworkbook` object then you should do it like this:

```
Application.Run "Thisworkbook.MacroForSheet1"
```

or in your case,

```
Application.Run "v1"
```

And put this in a `Module`. Insert it by *VBE > Insert > Module*.
Btw, you can do it like what @thienkhoi tran posted.
That will work as well in your situation. 
I proposed `Application.Run` so you can run macro in any location, `Public` or `Private`.

Comment: I did what you have suggested

I get the following error

Run Time Error 1004 'Application Defined or Object Defined Error'

Comment: @Adrian What Error and what line? Where do you write your macro? Module, Sheet? Are they Public?

Comment: @Adrian Cool! Don't post all, just the significant snippet of it. Btw, please answer my previous questions.

Comment: @Adrian Ok post a sample code. I suspect it is event driven?

Comment: @Adrian Nah, I'm good. I posted an edit. Again, you need to write the `cf1` macro in a `Module`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a sub to run all macro subs.
You have:

```
Sub macro1()   
   // code 1
End Sub
Sub macro2()   
   // code 2
End Sub
Sub macro3()   
   // code 3
End Sub
```

And you should create a macro:

```
Sub totalMcr()
  macro1
  macro2
  macro3
End Sub
```

And run only totalMcr() for all Macros. 
For custom UI (ribon button or context menu...), you can use the tool **Office custom UI editor**

Comment: You should use v1 only instead of Application.Run "v1"